# Continuous array key in foreach loop outputs

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, key

I have two arrays (say, $arrayA and $arrayB) with numerous values in them.

I would like to fill a list of 8 divs with these values using a foreach loop which has has just 4 divs in it, with each div increasing an incremental key from their respective array.

The following should hopefully illustrate:

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
    echo
    '<div class="type-a">' . $arrayA[i] . '</div>
    <div class="type-b">' . $arrayB[i] . '</div>
    <div class="type-a">' . $arrayA[i+1] . '</div>
    <div class="type-b">' . $arrayB[i+1] . '</div>';
 }

 <div class="type-a"> A1 </div>
 <div class="type-b"> B1 </div>
 <div class="type-a"> A2 </div>
 <div class="type-b"> B2 </div>
 <div class="type-a"> A3 </div>
 <div class="type-b"> B3 </div>
 <div class="type-a"> A4 </div>
 <div class="type-b"> B4 </div>
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: you can try to do loop based on len(array), then i:0 i+=2, then get the first and second array from a and b

Answer (score 0):

After your comment regarding differences in length, you can count the size of each to determine which is bigger and then iterate over that one as the main array:

```
<?php
# Make sure each value is an array
$arrayA = (empty($arrayA))? [] : array_values($arrayA);
$arrayB = (empty($arrayB))? [] : array_values($arrayB);
# Determine which array is longer
if(count($arrayA) >= count($arrayB)) {
    $arr_L = $arrayA;
    $arr_S = $arrayB;
}
else {
    $arr_L = $arrayB;
    $arr_S = $arrayA;
}
# Iterate over the larger array
foreach($arr_L as $key => $value): ?>

<!-- Just echo the value here because you are iterating this array -->
<div class="type-a"> <?php echo $value ?> </div>

<!-- Use the current key from this array to fetch the value from the B array -->
<div class="type-b"> <?php echo $arr_S[$key] ?> </div>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: In actuality the arrays are not equal, in some cases ArrayA may have more values, and in other ArrayB may have more

Comment: You have to determine which array is larger and iterate over that one. See edit.